# Communication between a controller and a separate task

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq

I have a task that may take some time to be completed.

I am using [RabbitMqBundle](https://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle)

but I have a doubt about how to implement the following workflow:

1. The user executes the action
2. The system generates a unique key, call the producer and then returns the key to the user
3. The user makes AJAX call (sending the key) getting the task status

In the meantime:

1. Consumer reads the message
2. Start the process
3. while processing updates the task status
4. at the end marks the task complete

the problem is: **How I can update the status of the task?**

Comment: Have you found solution already?

Comment: nop. the solution was try other way :(